# How to modify a jar package code then re-export a updated jar package?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I open a `newpro-01.jar` package:

[image]

I can add it as a library, so I can see the code.

but now I want to modify the code, then export a updated jar package.  how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you can open it in any archive opener such as 7-zip.

If you want to change java code you need to de-compile it using jd-gui and do what your code changes and make jar again.

[jd-gui download link](http://java-decompiler.github.io/)

Comment: Decompiling a java code is highly discouraged. One should have the original code to edit it.

Comment: I can confirm that the method described by @virajwee works. I did successfully replace a compiled class in jar library with another class, created with modified de-compiled source code. But in our case it was a legal and permitted operation, ymmv. Technically it should work. I also remember it is important to keep the directory structure (packages).